# PHP: Open a file on the server for download?

Tags: php, file, download

I have a PDF on my server. Now I want to open this file so the user can download it using the browser. How can I do that? I dont want to read the file or anything, its already on the server, just need to download it ...

Thanks?

Answer (score 2):

Please be more specific, is your server a web server?  If so, you can simply add the pdf somewhere in your root directory and navigate to it directly in a web browser and it should automatically download.

ie http://whateveryoursiteis.com/testpdf.pdf

Comment: I think I cant do that. The webserver im testing this with is an Apache. I cant just use a link to go there, it has to be a PHP an automatic command.

Comment: Yes you can, just enable the follow sym link in your htaccess

Answer (score 1):

there are differenct options:

First: if its in your htdocs folder, just link to it ( http://example.com/myfile.pdf )

Second: you could use the x-sendfile header. it is not supported by all servers. make sure to read the docs to find out what your server provides

third: you could set the appropriate header (Content-Type, Content-Length, etc) and then read the file via the readfile function

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache server, you can add this code to your VirtualHost config, or to your .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(pdf|PDF)">
  ForceType application/pdf
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$doc = 'path/to/doc.pdf';
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf');
readfile($doc);
```

will be download as downloaded.pdf