# Forbidden access to files in a specific folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a directory `files` that contains files that I don't want to allow to be accessed directly
If you go to www.mywebiste.com/files/myfile.pdf then you would be redirected.

However I want the files to be accessible from the rest of the site.
ie. I may have a page www.mywebiste.com/dave/page/ that needs to be able to display files from within the files dir.

I have tried the following htacccess in the files dir, but it's not working:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.mywebiste.com/files/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=404,L]
```

- If I could get this working, I assume that this would also prevent the files from being indexed by robots, as they too would be redirected?

Comment: No possible solution is waterproof: you need your uses to access these files so they'll always have some way to access. I suggest you just do not protect your files and let the users download them if they choose to. You can use `robots.txt` to prevent indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule ^files/.*$ - [F]
```

You may also use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?mywebiste.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^files/.*$ - [F]
```

Since the refer comes from the page it was called the page could be anything within your domain so I simple use `^http://(www.)?mywebiste.com/.*$` you may as well use `^http://(www.)?mywebiste.com` if you feel more comfortable with.
If refer is empty and folder is files deny access to it.

*PS: `http://(www.)?mywebiste.com` means either site address have `www.` or doesn't.*

---

As for robots you could use user agent to allow access even when the refer is empty.

`robots.txt` example:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /files/
```

[**More information about `robots.txt` see here.**](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?hl=en)

Comment: Why not use the way more common robots.txt to deny access

Comment: @dtech because not all robots respect it ? And he did not wish to prevent bots from indexing it just people from accessing it directly from what I understood.

Comment: Thanks @Prix, however when I use that code I am still able to access the file directly and from within the site. Am I meant to add the file to the root directory or the files directory?.. thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't it better if the condition be something like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mywebiste.com`?

Comment: Nice answer. Also, does it mean that someone faking a robot user agent would be able to get the file? I guess that there's no way around that.

Comment: @jon I am placing it on the root folder, when I try to access /files/style.css for example I get forbidden as expected.

Comment: And why should the robots have access to the files? :)

Comment: @didierc ofc they would, do you have better suggestion ? You could as well spoof the refer that is another bypass.

Comment: @HashemQolami yes its one option I opted for empty refer because he wants to catch direct access which usually comes with empty refer, he didnt mention links being on different sites or hotlinked.

Comment: @HashemQolami robots would have direct access to the files for indexing as he asked.

Comment: @Prix Is there a better way to do this, to also prevent hotlinks?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I suppose the only way would be some sort of robot IP white listing, but no such thing exists yet.

Comment: @Prix, actually I didn't want robots to have access so should I remove the line RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(googlebot|adsbot-google|bingbot|msnbot|psbot|gigabot|twitterbot|linkedinbot|yahoo-mmcrawler|pingdom\.com_bot) [NC]

Comment: @Jon, it seems you cannot have a bullet proof robots filtering mechanism. Prix solution is correct wrt your requirements I think (if you want robots in).

Comment: Let the robots index the page which containing the links of files ;)

Comment: @jon Yes you should, you should also implement a robots.txt to deny them as well not all may respect it but some do.

Comment: Have also updated an example to consider the refers for only your site.

Comment: Thanks @Prix that example is awesome, so that should also prevent robots from indexing the folder... including ones that would ignore a robots.txt

Comment: Yes you can include rules on the `robots.txt` to prevent some of the robots of being greedy and you can as well add the HTML tags to your links to prevent it from following it.

Comment: @jon have updated at the bottom a very simple sample of robots.txt

Comment: @Prix, Perfect... really appreciate your help... So i have robots text to tell 'good' robots to not index that dir, and I have the htaccess file to redirect any direct access to that file by 'bad' robots. I am not fussed if they index the file from other areas of the site, so that is perfect... thanks again J

Comment: @HashemQolami well spotted but not actually necessary if he does redirect www to non-www and vice-verse I believe.

Comment: @Prix I considered both situation. feel free to remove it.

Comment: @HashemQolami not at all, you're right given that he doesn't do what I have mentioned, was just mentioning that in that case it would not be necessary.

Comment: @jon well there are other ways like https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en there is also the nofollow https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en not sure how they apply to files but I believe those would help as well. **Ultimately you could make a protected content that is served by a PHP script or other language of your preference to logged in/registered users.**

Comment: Thanks @Prix, I will take a look at those links. The rest of the site is login based. I didn't want to place the actual files outside of the webroot, as a lot of the site once logged in requires the files, I just wanted something to protect them from being directly accessed, by robots and unlogged in users. J

Comment: @jon you can server the files using a php that before serving it verify if the user is logged in or not. It would then read the file and serve it's content to the user be it as download or on screen display using the PHP file so if the files are on a folder before root only your php would be able to access the files and server it to the users.

Comment: @Prix, So how would I go about doing this?... would it be that image links for example would be referenced like <img src="myphp.php?fileId=3" />,  the myphp.php would then use file_get_contents if authorised?

Comment: @jon yes similar `<a href="/files.php?filename=test.pdf">test.pdf</a>` and when the user tries to access it, it would verify his session first and you do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9981142/342740 see joschua011's answer, you can also make the URL's like `/files/test.pdf` internally redirect to the `/files.php?filename=test.pdf` to make the URL friendly and if its indexed it would show the login page or a error message if not logged in as you specify it.

Comment: Thanks @Prix, I will take a look, do you think this going to provide alot more security than having them as they are with the htaccess file as you have it above?

Comment: @jon yes and no, if your site is public and anyone can register, they can easily make a cURL request to automatically download the files for example. However generally speaking yes, it would be more secure, as the files would not be accessible within your domain anymore as they would be stored on an internal folder and accessed by the PHP only.

Comment: Okay, so as long as the site isn't open (which its not)... then it should be fine... basically I want to prevent people that aren't logged in from being able to access the files, and the only way they would be able to do that is by directly accessing the files... so I think your htaccess file should do the trick from preventing them to do that. Out of interest as long as your server is secure, then if files are kept out of the public_html folder they should be safe?

Comment: @jon yes, the files outside the root folder are not accessible via HTTP access which in this sense you would not need to do anything to protect it. As for the htaccess yes but any one with basic knowledge on the field would be able to emulate refer to directly download your files which is a bypass which is why its not a very good protective way to do it

Comment: @Prix "@dtech because not all robots respect it ?". Robots who not respect robots.txt also wouldn't report a robot user agent (after all the user agent header is set by the user, not the server)

Comment: @Prix.. thanks for that, I appreciate the time you've spent helping me... I guess I need to weigh up the level of security needed... if I do go down the route of storing files outside of the web directory I will probably be opening a new stackoverflow question on how to htaccess rewrite the filenames to the php file... alteranatevly I need to try and understand htaccess better... thanks again for all your help.. regards J

Comment: @dtech, I think Prix is basically saying that if I really want to make the files secure then they need to be kept out of the web directory.